# separate by pattern (word) in tidyr and dplyr

Tags: r, string, dplyr, tidyr

I have a very simple need: split a column into two new columns inside a chain of dplyr pipes. The trick here is doing it using a specific word as separator instead a single character.

the data:

```
id    elements
1     banana and apple
2     orange and lemon
3     house and flat
```

expected outcome

```
id    element1    element2
1      banana      apple
2      orange      lemon
3      house       flat
```

obviously, the tidyr::separate approach is not working as expected (my bad). Separation is done by first letter of word “and”.

```
df %>% tidyr::separate(elements, into = c("element1","element2"), sep = "and")
```

I know this maybe can be achieved with other verbs but my main target is to do it using dplyr and tidyr if possible.

Comment: can you `dput` your data?

Comment: @Forge It is not clear when you say not working as expected?  I am getting the output correctly.  Just to remove the spaces, I added the `\\s*`.  Can you show your output when you use separate

Comment: It Is separating by first letter in “and” . The “a”

Answer (score 3):

We can specify the space before and after the and as well to remove them

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   separate(elements, into = c('element1', 'element2'),
          sep = '\\s*and\\s*')
```

-output

```
#  id element1 element2
#1  1   banana    apple
#2  2   orange    lemon
#3  3    house     flat
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, elements = c("banana and apple", 
"orange and lemon", 
"house and flat")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```