# Split column depending on several patterns in R

Tags: r, string, tidyr

Some data processing work I needs to do is split a column depending on several words. For the sake of simplicity let's say I have only two words (after and before)

Example data

```
data <- structure (list(author=c("joe","mack","rick"),options=c("bike before run","car after bike","bus after bike")), class= "data.frame", row.names=c(NA,-3L))
```

output:

```
author  new1   new2
joe     bike   run
mack    car    bike
rick    bus    bike
```

Tried using tidyr to no avail

```
data %>% tidyr::separate(options, into=c("new1","new2"),sep="after|before")
```

Comment: Can you show your `packageVersion('tidyr')`  There is a similar question somebody asked couple of hours back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696779/separate-by-pattern-word-in-tidyr-and-dplyr/66696827#66696827).  This is working for me with `1.1.2` version

Comment: This worked for me as well on `1.1.3`. If you try what @akrun suggests and you have an old version you can update with `install.packages("tidyr")` as long as your Rstudio version and dependencies are current enough for the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape)

data %>% cbind(.,colsplit(data$options, "after|before", c("new1", "new2"))) %>%
      select(-options)
```